# MySql - Bad format for Time 'hhh:mm:ss' in column x

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I am trying to get difference between two timestamp value and storing the result in time column. But sometimes the result comes in 'hhh:mm:ss' format. While trying to access that column in Java using Result.getTime(), it is throwing error saying '**Bad format for time in column x**'.

To get better idea, store the result of following query in time column and try to access this value in Java.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2013-01-26 19:03:48','2013-02-15 06:59:36'))) as 'RESULT';
```

What should I do to get result even if it has 'hhh:mm:ss' format (without any error)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: modified the description. thanks

Comment: @Prateek - my friend question is not clear. Mysql timestampdiff function return time difference in the hour:min:sec format. if the hour difference is more than 99 then it will hhh format . what is the problem in it? Please try to explain your requirement so we can give you solution

Comment: @Fathah: The problem is when I am trying to access this 'hhh:mm:ss' format values, Java gives 'Bad format for time' exception. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @Prateek - You are running mysql query and you are getting result as hhh:mm:ss and you wanna process it in java right?

Comment: @Prateek - If your answer is 'yes' for my above question, then check my answer

Comment: @Prateek - I'm sure it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you run query and result set contain the result

```
String hourMinSec=resultset.getString("RESULT");
String[]result=hourMinSec.split(":");
int hour=Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
int min=Integer.parseInt(result[1]);
int second=Integer.parseInt(result[2]);
```

Expressing difference between two dates as date is meaningless i think. Just to answer your question if you want to create time  you can use following

```
 Time time =new Time(hour, min, second);
```

But i feel its meaningless.

Comment: @Fathah : On Java Side, I am storing this value in java.sql.Time object & it is throwing that error.
On UI Side, I am simply displaying this value as Hour Minute & Second.

Comment: @Fathah: Suppose value in that column is '10:10:10'. I am getting this value in java using : Time result = resultSet.getTime(); And at that time I am getting 'Bad format for time' exception

Answer (score 1):

You can't express the difference between two dates as another date. For example if you will got 31 days difference you can't say if it is 1 month or 1 month and 1 day.

You should create your own object to storage this data.